# Moving Specific elements in an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to accomplish swapping elements in an array in a specific manner.

I have created a 1-D array but I display it in 2-D. The goal is to swap elements from one position to the other. I have developed my own swapping code below that lets user choose which element he wants to switch with the other element.

My question or where i need help with is how can I have the user let say input A0 and swap whats at A0 with A1.

Below is the code I have been trying to develop this solution but cant implement both ideas together.

So essentially right now A0 = 4 and A1 = 3. So the goal is to have A0 = 3 and A3 = 4. Below at the top of the code is a reference table I created to see the initial array.
in the future i would also like to develop another input where the user can input either L or R to swap either left of the element or right of the element.. but that would be a worry for another time. After i understand how to work this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//     0 1 2 3 4
//    ------------  //
// A | 4 3 2 1 5  | //    In  1-d A is 0-4 elements
// B | 7 6 8 9 10 | //    In  1-d B is 5-9 elements
//    ------------

int main()
{
    int number[10] = { 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10 };
    int temp = 0;
    int src = 0;
    int des;
    int n = 0;
    // Below was me trying to take an user input to move within elements in A. Its flawed because if n is greater that 4 it goes into B section which is what I dont need.
    cout << "Choose an n: " << endl;
    cin >> n; // The n helps to direct Which position in A so if i want to acces A4 the n needed to input is 4
    int A = number[0 + n];
    int B = number[5 + n];
    cout << A << endl;

    cout << "Before the swap array is: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << number[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Choose starting position" << endl;
    cin >> src;
    cout << "Choose ending position" << endl;
    cin >> des;

    temp = number[src];
    number[src] = number[des];
    number[des] = temp;
    cout << "After the swap the array is:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << number[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also here is online view of how it currently runs...... https://onlinegdb.com/Sk2DEDG9S

Comment: Please format your code before you post it here. If your IDE does not support code formating you can use http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: I'm Sorry ill take a look into before for any other future post

Comment: `std::swap( number[src], number[des] );`  -- Otherwise, I don't understand what the issue is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: I also don't understand the problem. What is the exact input from the user?

Comment: Why do you believe your current code does not work? How does your observed behavior differ from your expected behavior?

Comment: So i want the User to input A0 which access the element 4 and swap that with the element at A1.

Comment: Why does the user enter `n`? `n` is only used to assign `A` and `B` but then it's not used.

Comment: n was my way to see if i could access elements in A. So if i wanted to access element at A4 i would need n to be 4. Its just there for my own testing.

Comment: So you are looking for `std::string src, dst; std::cin >> src >> dst; std::swap(numbers[(src[0] == 'A' ? 0 : 5) + src[1] - '0'], numbers[(dst[0] == 'A' ? 0 : 5) + dst[1] - '0']);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read both inputs `src` and `dst` as string.

```
std::string src, dst;
std::cin >> src >> dst;
```

You can determine the indexes with

```
int idxSrc = (src[0] == 'A' ? 0 : 5) + src[1] - '0';
int idxDst = (dst[0] == 'A' ? 0 : 5) + dst[1] - '0';
```

If the user enters e.g. `A3` the index is determined as 0 + 3 = 3. If the user enters `B2` the index is determined as 5 + 2 = 7. On system with `'A' + 1 == 'B'` you could also

```
int idxSrc = 5 * (src[0] - 'A') + src[1] - '0';
int idxDst = 5 * (src[0] - 'A') + dst[1] - '0';
```

Then you can swap them with

```
std::swap(numbers[idxSrc], numbers[idxDst]);
```

Comment: In your example the indexes are from my array or just general? Because the index in my A3 = 1 and not 3?

Comment: @Elchavo18 Now I believe your question is not clear for me. Are you trying to convert a 2-D index like `B3` to a 1-D index like `8` or are you trying to convert a 1-D index to another 1-D index? What is `number` in that case? EDIT: I changed my question. Now I'm taking the index from the array `number`

Comment: Sorry I think my question was not clear enough and recognize it. Thank you for the patience. So I have a 1-D array In my case i like to display it as a 2-d array in the terminal. I guess the best way i want to explain my goal is like a chess game. I want to move/swap A0 to the A1 position so if you look in my reference table change the 4 with the 3.

Comment: @Elchavo18 Ok, I undid my change. Now my algorithm should do it. If the user enters `'A0'` and `'A1'` it will swap the values 4 and 3.

Comment: Thank you sorry for the confusion ill try implementing now!

Comment: Just for clarification what does the "?" operator do? I'm just trying to understand the code

Comment: @Elchavo18 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator